# Hide cursor if window looses focus?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to hide the cursor if the window looses the focus ? e.g. 'windmove-left moves the focus one window left but the cursor can still be seen in the windows that is no longer active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the purpose of user option **`cursor-in-non-selected-windows`**.

```
cursor-in-non-selected-windows is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is t

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

Documentation:
Non-nil means show a cursor in non-selected windows.
If nil, only shows a cursor in the selected window.
If t, displays a cursor related to the usual cursor type
(a solid box becomes hollow, a bar becomes a narrower bar).
You can also specify the cursor type as in the `cursor-type' variable.
Use Custom to set this variable and update the display.

You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: The following call worked for me: (setq-default cursor-in-non-selected-windows nil)

Comment: Precisely - that's what you need to do.